# Prove $M,n,p,q>0$, if $\frac{m}{n}\lt\frac{p}{q},$ show $\frac{m}{n}\lt\frac{m+p}{n+q}\lt\frac{p}{q},$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove the following inequality

Given :$M,n,p,q>0$,

> $$\frac{m}{n}\lt\frac{p}{q},$$

To show:

> $$\frac{m}{n}\lt\frac{m+p}{n+q}\lt\frac{p}{q},$$

I would like to solve it myself so maybe a hint would help. I am working ahead of class so I am not sure what I am doing ;)  I've tried to manipulate the inequality in different ways but did not get anywhere...
I am sure the solution is quite simple, and maybe with a hint, I can figure it out myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left inequality is true because
$$\frac{m+p}{n+q}-\frac{m}{n}=\frac{np-mq}{n(n+q)}>0$$

and $\frac{m}{n}<\frac{p}{q}$ gives $mq<np$.

A proof of the right inequality we can get by the same way.

Comment: Sorry in the not Mathjax  version I forgot to add that m/n<p/q, i will add it

Comment: @Petra I also fixed. See now.

Comment: Many thanks and Dankeschön :)

Comment: You are welcome, @Petra! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Since all numbers are positive, you simply have to use this rule:

> Let $a,b,c,d\:$ be positive numbers. Then 
>   $$\frac ab<\frac cd\iff ad<bc.$$

Indeed, your left inequality, for instance, reduces to
$$m(n+q)<n(m+p)\iff  mq<np, $$
which is another form of the hypothesis.